# Prove for $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ open and bounded: $\exists C\in \mathbb{R}$ s.t. $u\in C_c^1(\Omega) \implies \int |u| \leq C \int |Du|$

Tags: calculus, partial-differential-equations

> Let $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be open and bounded. Show that $C(\Omega) \in \mathbb{R}$ exists such that for all $u\in C_c^1(\Omega)$:
>
> $\int_\Omega|u|d\mathcal{L}^n\leq C(\Omega)\int_\Omega |Du|d\mathcal{L}^n$

I have no clue how to prove this, yet it should be simple. This was an exercise given as part of an introductionary PDEs course, though I am at a loss as to how to relate this to anything in particular we have proven so far (harmonic functions, fundamental solutions, Poisson/Laplace equation, distributions, ...). Intuitively, the statement seems somewhat plausible. But I have no place to start.

Any tips/sketches appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the famous Poincaré-inequality.

You start the following way: Fix some arbitrary $(x_1, ...., x_{n-1}, x)\in \Omega$.

As $\Omega$ is bounded, we can find $a\leq b$ such that $a\leq x \leq b$ for every $x$. Extend $u$ to $\tilde{u} \in C_c^1(\mathbb{R}^n)$ where you set $\tilde{u}(x) := u(x)$ if $x \in \Omega$ and $\tilde{u}(x) := 0$ if $x \in \mathbb{R}^n \setminus \Omega$. Then use $$
\lvert \tilde{u}(x_1, ..., x_{n-1}, x) \rvert = \lvert \tilde{u}(x_1, ..., x_{n-1}, x) - \tilde{u}(x_1, ..., x_{n-1}, a) \rvert
$$
(to see this think about where $\tilde{u}$ vanishes) to prove that
$$
\lvert \tilde{u}(x_1, ..., x_{n-1}, x) \rvert \leq \int^b_a \lvert \partial_n \tilde{u}(x_1, ..., x_{n-1}, s) \rvert~\mathrm{d}s \leq \int^b_a \lvert D\tilde{u}(x_1, ..., x_{n-1}, s) \rvert~\mathrm{d}s.
$$
Integrate this inequality over $x \in [a, b]$ and then again over $(x_1, ..., x_{n-1}) \in \mathbb{R}^n$. Then, by using a famous analysis theorem and looking at the support of $\tilde{u}$, convince yourself that this is already
$$
\int_{\Omega} \lvert u \rvert\mathrm{d}\mathcal{L}^n \leq C\int_{\Omega} \lvert Du \rvert\mathrm{d}\mathcal{L}^n.
$$

**A quick remark:** This inequality even holds for the Sobolev space $H^{1, 1}_0(\Omega)$ (that hopefully will be or already have been introduced in your PDE class), because $C_c^1(\Omega)$ is dense in this space.

The inequality even holds for every exponent $p$ (then on $C_c^1(\Omega)$ and $H^{1, p}_0(\Omega)$, i.e.
$$
\int_{\Omega} \lvert u \rvert^p\mathrm{d}\mathcal{L}^n \leq \tilde{C}\int_{\Omega} \lvert Du \rvert^p\mathrm{d}\mathcal{L}^n
$$
although $\tilde{C}$ will have to be chosen differently.

You can also convince yourself that the assumption of $u$ having compact support is necessary.